# An easy half of Quillen-Suslin theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

**Michael Artin's Algebra, exercise 14.9.4, mixed with the context**

> Suppose $V$ is a finitely generated free module over the ring $R=\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_k]$. Let $A$ be a presentation matrix for $V$. Denote by $A(c)$ the evaluation of $A$ at a point of $\mathbb C^k$, viz. $x=(x_1,\dots,x_k)\mapsto c\in\mathbb C^k$. Then the rank of $A(c)$ is constant for any $c\in\mathbb C^k$.

What I all know is that $R$ is Noetherian. Since apparently, $R$ isn't PID when $n>1$, the structure theorem of finitely generated module doesn't apply. Moreover, after some searching work, I know that there's some commutative ring $R$ such that there's some maximal independent subset of cardinality $m\neq n$ in the free module $R^n$, therefore the properties of modules are quite different from those of vector spaces. After some messy tries, I have no result or no idea to proceed.

Any idea? Thanks!

**Edit.**

1. An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is called a *presentation matrix* of an $R$-module $M$ iff  $M\simeq R^m/AR^n$, where $AR^n=\{\,AX\colon X\in R^n\,\}$ is a submodule of $R^m$. Note that even a free module could have a collection of dependent generators with relations. It seems strange, but obvious after a second glance.
2. I misunderstood the proposition about the module. The original thread is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33321/20948). It's true that the cardinality of the independent set is no greater than the rank of the free module. It could be easily proved by Cayley-Hamilton theorem. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47846/20948).

Comment: For a commutative ring A with 1, there is no injective A-module map from A^m to A^n if m>n.

Comment: The ring A we require is not the zero ring in the statement.

Comment: I think the answer here is more clear than the answer below
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741754/am-i-interpreting-artin-theorem-14-9-1-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_m$ be the column vectors of matrix $A$. Suppose $V$ is isomorphic to $R^k$. Then we have an exact sequence  $R^m \to R^n\to R^k \to 0$. Let matrix $B$ denote the second map and let $C_1,\ldots, C_k$ such that $B(C_1,\ldots,C_k)=I_k$. On the other hand, show that $R^n$ is the direct sum of the module $\langle A_1,\ldots,A_m\rangle$ and the module generated by $C_i$'s. In other words, we can find a matrix $M$ such that $I_n = (A\mid C)M$. Since under any evaluation $v$ the later module is always of rank $k$, then matrix $C(v)$ is of rank $k$ hence the first module is of rank $n-k$, $A(v)$ is of rank $n-k$.

Comment: Seems true. The key point might be: once $V$ is free, the exact sequence $R^n\xrightarrow AR^m\to V\to0$ decomposes $R^m\approx(AR^n)\oplus V$, therefore there's some invariant of $AR^n$.